# Определение принадлежности адресов IPv4-сети

Tags: сеть, ip, ip-address

Может кто разбирается в этих IPv4, и сможет растолковать мне как это все работает..А то я ничего понять не могу, как найти эти адреса. Нужен только ход рассуждений, и понятное разъяснение решения данной задачи...

Маска сети для IPv4 адресации – это 4-х байтное число, которое делит IP адрес на адрес сети (первая часть) и адрес узла (вторая часть). Для части IP адреса, соответствующей адресу сети в маске сети содержатся двоичные единицы, а для части IP адреса, соответствующей адресу узла в маске сети содержаться двоичные нули. IP адрес, в котором в части адреса узла содержаться только двоичные нули – служебный адрес сети. IP адрес, в котором в части адреса узла содержаться только двоичные единицы – адрес ограниченного широковещания. Эти два адреса нельзя использоваться для адресации узлов.

Сеть с IPv4 адресацией задана одним из адресов, принадлежащих этой сети `(192.168.3.17)` и маской сети `(255.255.192.0)`. Определите, какие из перечисленных ниже адресов могут быть назначены устройствам в этой сети.

> 1. 192.168.3.255
> 2. 192.168.65.3
> 3. 192.168.33.0
> 4. 192.168.192.0
> 5. 192.168.63.255

Comment: а что именно непонятно? может http://jodies.de/ipcalc поможет? маска 255.255.192.0 - /18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошее объяснение, [@pyatak](/users/814/pyatak), но некоторые вещи намного проще объяснять с точки зрения математики. В данном случае воспользуемся бинарной. Нас даже просто интересуют логические операции, а сами системы счисления не играют роли.

Понятное дело, что [@Евгений536](/users/163/%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9536), может и не знать бинарных операций, но в таком случае я уж не знаю, какой смысл говорить о бинарном представлении маски (двоичных единицах и нулях), а так же пытаться постичь то, что построено на бинарной математике и логике.

Дело вот в чем: если хост принадлежит сети - рассчет диапазона адресов выполняется двумя логическими операциями `and` и `or`, с последней еще необходимо отрицание.

Итак, каждый октет (байт) IP-адреса соответствует октету (байту) маски, зная это, мы используем операцию `and` для каждого из октетов попарно

192 and 255 = 192

168 and 255 = 168

3 and 192 = 0

17 and 0 = 0

Как видно, мы получили новый адрес - адрес сети: 192.168.0.0 (т.е. это самый минимальный адрес нашего диапазона).

Дальше ничего сложного так же нету, нам нужен широковещательный адрес (самый максимальный адрес диапазона). Для этого, нам придется первым делом проинвертировать (от максимального числа, представимого 8ю битами (байтом) - 255, отнять число маски) байты маски. Итак,

192 or (!255 = 0) = 192

168 or (!255 = 0) = 168

3 or (!192 = 63) = 63

17 or (!0 = 255) = 255

Здесь мы получили наш широковещательный 192.168.63.255 адрес.

Таким образом получается, что все, что строго больше сети и строго меньше широковещательного адреса - входит в наш диапазон.

Можно поступить по-другому, применить операцию `and` поочередно ко всем данным вариантам ответов и сравнивать результаты с адресом сети. Т.к. все адреса, входящие в подсеть, должны иметь один и тот же адрес сети.

Comment: Ого, классно! а это точно 100% рабочий способ? дайте ссылку пожалуйста почитать про это...! это все понятно что вы написали, но непонятно почему именно так, почему если использовать побитовое И то получим адрес сети

Comment: Да это точно так. Этот метод используется повсеместно (компьютеры, роутеры и пр.), чтобы определить находится ли получатель в той же сети, что и отправитель. От этого будет зависеть, куда отправится пакет на шлюз или в сеть. Но это уже игры с другими протоколами, более низкими (Layer 2 - Ethernet).Прочитать об этом можно у CISCO. "Основы организации сетей Cisco".Функцией "И" является (если грубо) выделение только тех разрядов, в которых в обоих числах были единицы. А дальше, спроектирован IPv4 был таким образом, чтобы вычисления работали как можно скорее.

Comment: Почитайте историю начиная с адресации основанной на классах IP-сетей. Затем доберетесь до того, зачем понадобилась маска и как она работает и для чего.

Answer (score 3):

Ох не мучили вас в институте или не мучают.
Ну что ж смотри, мой юный падаван, дан хост с адресом `192.168.3.17`, и маска `255.255.192.0`, сказали еще что хост принадлежит сети.
Давай для начала переведем в человеко-формат.
Делаем вот что, все рассчитывают в двоичной системе а мы с тобой сделаем хак и через десятичную рассчитаем.
Берем с лева первый октет который не равен `255`, это октет номер `3` он равен `192`.
Именно он нам интересен.
`256-192 = 64`, `64` это шаг, который поможет найти адрес сети.
Он еще не раз встретится в решении. Берем адрес который нам дали в задаче `192.168.3.17`, и смотрим на `3-ий` октет, так как именно он нам интересен.
Берем число 64, и 3-ий октет - это 3. Так как 3 < 64, то, ахтунг, адрес сети будет `192.168.0.0`.
Если бы нам дали хост `192.168.73.17`, то адрес сети был бы `192.168.64.0`, а если `192.168.128.17` то `192.168.128.0`.
Понимаешь к чему я?
То есть, с шагом в `64` мы смотрим если число `<= 64` то ставим `64`, если больше то `64+64=128` и тоже самое с `128`.
Если больше `128`, то `128+64=192` и т.д.
Круто знаем адрес сети `192.168.0.0`.
Далее найдем `broadcast-широковещательный адрес`.
Это уже проще.
К `3` октету адреса сети прибавляем шаг, он у нас `64`.
Получаем `192.168.64.0`, дальше нужно просто от `64` отнять константу, она равна `1`, а последний октет заменить на `255`.
Получим `192.168.63.255`.
Это широковещательный адрес.
Все!
Получили диапазон от `192.168.0.0` до `192.168.63.255`.
Теперь смотрим какие адреса в него попадают, `192.168.3.255,192.168.33.0`.
Вообще конечно такие адреса фактически могут и не работать но касательно задачи это скорее всего будет правильным ответом.

Comment: я еще в школе =)

Comment: Тогда, уроки делать пора...)

Comment: [отстань, дядя, мы маски считаем](http://bash.im/quote/417229)

Comment: не подскажите, где про это все(как рассчитывать и т.д) можно почитать по подробней? а то в интернете нашел на википедии там столько мути всякой..

Answer (score -2):

Вот ещё сайт полезный в помощь: http://ip-calculator.ru/

Comment: Нужно вставлять полный ответ, во избежании недоступности ресурса.